# Delphi FMX OpenDialog is missiong OPtions list

Tags: delphi

I added a TOPenDialog component to a form and am writing the menu method to operate it. I copied code from a VCl project including the line `openDialog1.Options := [ofReadOnly];`.

The compiler rejects it since ofReadOnly (and other options) are not recognized.  The TopenOptions type is included in VCL.Dialogs but does not seem to appear in the FMX version.

I am currently using the Delphi starter version which does not include the FMX.dialogs.pas file text so I cannot add the options into the unit.  WIll including the VCL.dialogs file in the Uses section fix this?  I have heard that it is not a good idea to mix VCL and  FMX units together in the same program.

Comment: Why would you expect to mix FMX and VCL. That makes no sense. Why don't you just do the obvious thing and read the documentation? Augment that with the fact the FMX enums are declared with the SCOPENENUMS compiler directive enabled.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  Ease back a little!  I am new to this and I am reading the documentation. When I don't understand something I ask questions of people who know such as this site.

Answer (score 3):

If you read Embarcadero's documentation, you will see that the [`FMX.Dialogs.TOpenDialog.Options`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Dialogs.TOpenDialog.Options) property uses the same [`System.UITypes.TOpenOptions`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UITypes.TOpenOptions) type that the [`VCL.Dialogs.TOpenDialog.Options`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TOpenDialog.Options) property uses, so both dialogs have the same options available.

The reason your code is not compiling is because the [`TOpenOption`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UITypes.TOpenOption) enum has been declared with the [`{SCOPEDENUMS ON}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Scoped_Enums_(Delphi)) directive enabled (see [Scoped Enumerations](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Scoped_Enumerations)).  You need to prefix scoped enum values with their containing enum type name, eg

```
uses
  ..., System.UITypes;

OpenDialog1.Options := [TOpenOption.ofReadOnly];
```

Comment: Your line produces a compiler error -  [dcc32 Error] FmxMain.pas(343): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TOpenOptions' and 'Set'.

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. I tested in XE2 and Seattle (I don't have Berlin+ installed). The code I showed compiles fine for me in both versions. What version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: Nope, it works, I can't read between Topenoptions and topenoption.  Thanks for helping a newbie.